# In oracle, can I associate a default Schema with my USER ID where SCHEMA <> USERID?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to connect to an Oracle database with UserId "MY_SCHEMA" and then be able to perform queries where the table name was not qualified with the schema name:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

When executing SQL, I would like my unqualified queries to go against a different schema other than my own. In other words, I would like this to be equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_OTHER.TABLE1
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.TABLE1
```

I know it seems a little weird and so I expect that this is not possible.

I do not have any sort of admin rights to the database to see if I can associate a default schema with a login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you login, you can run the following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=schema_other;
```

If you really want this to happen automatically, you can create a system trigger for the logon action that looks for your username and uses `execute immediate` to run the `alter session` command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_schema_logon
   AFTER LOGON
   ON DATABASE
BEGIN
   IF SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') = 'MY_SCHEMA' THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=schema_other';
   END IF;
END my_schema_logon;
/
```